# why does npm install fail when run in windows cmd but works fine when run from git bash or vs terminal?

Tags: windows, git, bash, cmd, npm-install

Tried running
npm install -g @angular/cli

and got the below error consistently. Tried running it as administrator as well, yet no result.

```
23286 error path C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
23287 error code EPERM
23288 error errno -4048
23289 error syscall open
23290 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng'
23290 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng'
23290 error   cause:
23290 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng'
23290 error      errno: -4048,
23290 error      code: 'EPERM',
23290 error      syscall: 'open',
23290 error      path: 'C:\\Users\\XX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng' },
23290 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \'C:\\Users\\XX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng\'',
23290 error   errno: -4048,
23290 error   code: 'EPERM',
23290 error   syscall: 'open',
23290 error   path: 'C:\\Users\\XX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ng' }
23291 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
23292 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Comment: Are you getting same error when trying from administrator as well ?

Comment: Hi Jiithin,
unfortunately yes, i tried opening the command prompt as Run as Administrator, yet the same issue.

Comment: the same error resolves in many way for different users, refer this link once "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1349" , many suggested different options , lets see any one resolves .. if nothing works, try changing the installation directory too,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about Windows, but this could happen if you're using the project folder somewhere else, or in a different tool, or an Anti-virus locking the the installation.

try running `npm cache clean` and then run `npm install`

Comment: Thank you theberbie.
I had to add -f to carry out the npm cache clean. but even after that error persists.
And i got the same error on git bash terminal too, but not at the same point during install but on a different module this time

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\XX\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\d
ashdash\node_modules'

So you may be right, there may be some process locking the installation.
But is this always going to be with trial and error. How can i identify which process is blocking it and see if i can do something about. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using a text editor that has the project folder(Sublime, Atom etc), close it and then run npm cache clean.

My understanding is that you still get an error, but now it has moved on to your node_modules, correct? 

If you're using an anti-virus, please try disabling it before running `npm cache clean` and then `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

> there may be some process locking the installation.
>   But is this always going to be with trial and error. How can i identify which process is blocking it and see if i can do something about

Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (simple exe, no setup required): with it, you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for "`Roaming\npm`" for instance.
Any process with an handle still open on that folder will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks VonC! Let me give this a try.